# How to ask somebody if I may adress him/her with du in German?

Tags: conversation

I will have a B1 sprechen test in Goethe inistitue and I should handle a conversation with a partner.
From perspective of examiner, one of the important points is, if the examnee can use properly the `Du` and `Sie` in correct situations.

I am going to ask my partner if I may reference him with `du` using the below sentence:

```
Darf ich duzen ?
```

But, I am wondering, if there is a better and simpler sentence than this one ?

Comment: I'd argue that by asking that, you demonstrate already that you *cannot* properly use "du" and "Sie".

Comment: ***Jmdn.** duzen* means *addressing **so.** by 'du'*, so it is virtually always used with an object. Without object, one would say, e.g., *Darf ich du sagen?* or similiar.

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I think that English speakers learning German tend to worry about *du/Sie* more than they should. Formal vs. informal speech is a feature of many languages, and the German system is relatively simple compared to some, and actually very similar to first name/last name address in English. I'm sure that using *Sie* instead of *du* isn't the worst mistake one is likely to make on such a test.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is missing its object:

> Darf ich Sie duzen?

or

> Darf ich Dich duzen?

But mostly, we don't explicitly ask like this. How to address a person is often derived from indirect cues and the situation. For example, if your partner introduces themselves by their last name (say, "Miss Smith"), I'd go with "Sie" at least for the beginning. If your partner introduces themselves by their first name (say, "Susan"), I'd go with "Du". This is just an example, much of it is what you might call "reading the room". But as you both are language learners and by definition not too well versed in German customs, nobody will tear of your head off if you get it wrong and correct yourself later ;)

Comment: I agree that it's pretty clear when someone introduces themself by their last name, has a certain age and/or is a complete stranger. Otherwise (e.g. first name or no introduction at all, kind of familiar or youngish), i.e. in cases of doubt, there are also more natural to ask, e.g. *Darf ich du sagen?*

Answer (score 1):

The phrases "Darf ich Sie duzen?" ans "Darf ich Dich duzen?" are grammatically correct. But using *Dich* in "Darf ich Dich duzen?" anticipates a positive answer, thus I wouldn't recommend to say that.

Here are some suggestions:

- Wollen wir uns duzen?
- Wollen wir zum "Du" übergehen?
- Wollen wir "Du" sagen?
- Ich schlage vor, dass wir uns duzen.

Answer (score 0):

If persons don't know each other too well or have used the "Sie" for some time, it's an unwritten law that typically the older person offers the "du" to the younger one by saying something like

> Ich bin "Vorname".

The younger answers similarly, followed by a handshake<sup>1)</sup> or a toast<sup>2)</sup>.

The sentence quoted above

> Darf ich Du sagen?

is typically used by older persons interacting with teenagers (teachers, doctors, etc.), where it's unclear whether they are of age already or whether the younger cares. It typically does not imply that the asked person is to say "Du" to the asker. The "Sie" is generally on the retreat, and it's very common that people of the same age or within a group or in a company just use "Du".

So, while

> Darf ich Sie dutzen?

is correct, it's rarely openly asked. Either you offer the "Du" (by introducing yourself with the first name) or you somehow have the feeling that it's ok to do so.

<sup>1)</sup> unless COVID forbids so

<sup>2)</sup> if in a restaurant or a pub

Comment: Also "Nennen Sie mich Vorname" can be used instead of "Ich bin Vorname"

Comment: @Allerleirauh "Nennen Sie mich [Vorname]" does not necessarily imply *duzen*. For eaxmple, a waiter in a restaurant could offer that to you. Then you are allowed to say "Hans, bringen Sie mir bitte die Suppe."

Comment: @PaulFrost But then "Ich bin Vorname" does this not imply too... My point was, that for me "Nennen Sie mich Vorname" feels more like some agreement, than "Ich bin Vorname", which could be only information without suggestion.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Yes, it is the same with "Ich bin [Vorname]".  In both cases it depends on the context.

Comment: And, by the way, in some cases the surname is (or was) used in combination with "Du". For example, when I was a schoolboy, some teachers did that to address pupils. And it seems to be quite usual in the army among comrades:  "Meier, stell Dich nicht so an."

Comment: @PaulFrost: In the army, yes. But in school, I know it the other way round (especially in classes where the pupils are young adults). The teacher uses "Sie" with the first name.

Comment: @PMF When I was a schoolboy (long ago, I am 66 now), there was a great variety: First name + Du / surname + Du, and in the senior classes first name + Sie / surname + Sie /  Herr or  (yes, at that time!) Fräulein + surname + Sie.